# Python Requests with Tor

Tags: python, python-requests, tor, socks

Unable to use Tor with Python Requests

```
import requests
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5://localhost:9050',
    'https': 'socks5://localhost:9050'
}
url = 'http://httpbin.org/ip'
print(requests.get(url, proxies=proxies).text)
```

I have tried a multitude of solutions, none of which worked for me. I am trying to make simple requests with Python through Tor. Thanks in advance.

Error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='canihazip.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<
>   urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x031B77F0>:
>   Failed to esta blish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection
>   could be made because the ta rget machine actively refused it',))

Comment: Tor browser listens on port 9150, not 9050 (used by tor expert bundle / tor daemon).

Comment: Thank you this fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you `pip3 install requests[socks]`, or if using zsh, `pip3 install "requests[socks]"`

Then do this:

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://localhost:9050',
    'https': 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
}
session.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

**Note** The **`h`** in `socks5h://`

Also, you will have to have tor running on your computer (not the browser).  You can install tor using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) by running `brew install tor`.

You an start a tor instance by simply running `tor` in terminal.

Comment: I see a couple of problems, I'm on windows, and the "h" did not change anything for me..

Comment: I cannot find where to download homebrew, but I do have Tor browser running, yes.

Comment: @Vaxe Sorry I misread the homebrew docs.  It does **not** work on windows.  Also, I couldn't figure out how to run tor on windows, and you definitely are not the first person to ask.  If you figure it out you should let us know!

Comment: I had a related problem, socks was working on windows without `h` but not for my raspberry, adding `h` fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

drew010's comment should be the answer

> Tor browser listens on port 9150, not 9050 (used by tor expert bundle / tor daemon)